# Armor does not follow rig

Tags: modifiers, armature, parent, pose-mode

The shinguard part of the armor does not follow the rig.
[image]

However, when I select X mirroring I get better results but I won't be able to move the legs individually.
[image]

I'm not sure how I should parent the shoes since it has different attachments.

File: https://we.tl/t-U5C9IkAQZI

Thanks

Comment: Maybe apply the scale and rotation of the armature + objects, apply the Mirror, put the Subdivision Surface below the Armature modifier, recalculate the normals (some are inverted), join some of the objects, also it looks like you have 2 overlapping legs?